# An EventBus with vue3 and typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

There are many posts and examples about the vue 3 event bus pattern but with typescript I am running into an issue. My classes cannot find the exported event bus.

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './assets/tailwind.css'
import mitt from "mitt";

const emitter = mitt()
const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter

app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

home.vue

```
@Options({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
})
export default class Home extends Vue {

    name = ""
    age = 25


    counter(): void {
        this.age = this.age + 1
    }

    emitMethod () {
        this.emitter("test", 22); <-- emitter not found
        this.emitter.emit("test", 22) <--- nope
        emitter.emit("test", 22) <--- nope
    }
}
</script>
```

error
TS2339: Property 'emitter' does not exist on type 'HelloWorld'.

Since the emmiter is not found I thought I would try to export it again with useEmitter.js

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export default function useEmitter() {
    const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance();
    const emitter = internalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.emitter;

    return emitter;
}
```

Which did not work so then I tried

```
import mitt from "mitt";
export default mitt()
```

Which also did not work.

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm using Mitt with Vue 3. I'm injecting it like a service whenever its needed.

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'
import mitt from 'mitt';

const app = createApp(App)

const eventBus = mitt();
app.provide('eventBus', eventBus);

app.mount('#app');
```

```js
// component consuming event

export default {
    inject: [ 'eventBus' ],
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.eventBus.on('something', a => { this.doA(a); });
    },
    methods: {
        doA(a) {
            // do something
        }
    },
}
```

```js
// component emitting event

export default {
    inject: [ 'eventBus' ],
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: {
        emitSomething() {
            let a = 1;
            this.eventBus.emit('something', a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I am using the class component way I am not able to implement for imple. Seems `@Inject()` is no longer in vue 3. Thank you very much for posting. Hopefully it will help someone.

Comment: Can you share the link where it says it is not used anymore in Vue 3 please?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72539590/5525384.

Comment: ok... Looks like I need to learn how to do vue differently. Thank you!